# Find the inverse of the map

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to compute the inverse of
$$F(x,y)=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1},xy+\frac{1}{2}\log{\left(\frac{x+y}{y-x}\right)}\right)$$
in a suitable domain $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I have checked that $F$ is a local diffeomorphism by the Implicit function theorem, however I completely failed finding the inverse.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Seems hard, I tried to replace $x$ and $y$ by $s = x +y$ and $r = x-y$ and some polar equation, plus using $z = r + is$ since $\tan(\arg(z)) = \frac{s}{r}$ but without success... seems very hard with our a good geometric interpretation!

Comment: @JulesBesson, thanks! I know that we can change the log term by $atanh(x/y)$, but no more that it. I don't have a special geometric reason behind.

Comment: I got as far as $$\begin{cases}x=r\sinh t \\ y =r\cosh t\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+1 = r^2\cosh 2t + 1 \\2xy + 2\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) = r^2\sinh 2t + 2t\end{cases}$$ As you can see, unfortunately the $+2t$ term (corresponding to the log) makes this system of equations transcendental, meaning no inverse exists in terms of elementary functions. Substitutions should not introduce transcendentalism, only make them easier to spot.